# How do I use Raspberry Pi to create a web application for my sensors?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I recently bought many sensor to use with my pi, using the GPIO. All the scripts to retrieve data are ready, but now, I would like to store it in a database, and then thanks to an API, use it to display graphs, trigger alerts on a website hosted on github. The project is to build my own IoT plateform.

My question is the following one, regarding the needs of the project, what kind of database would you advise me ? I thought about the base SQL or SQLite, but I would like to do something more recent maybe, like noSQL, or Node.js. If anyone has ideas about that and advise, please feel free to answer !

Comment: Not a suitable question for this site.  You need to research the pros and cons yourself.

Comment: This question isn't related to raspberry pi.. Try to ask in the stackoverflow community.

Comment: The pros/cons of this issue are maddening to research and I'm glad to offer what I gleaned.

Comment: @Katte StackOverflow did not help me when I was researching.

Comment: @TomFrench your question is uncomfortably broad and not easily answered succinctly. We can probably work on it together to make it more useful to the site in general

Comment: I hesitate to edit your question since my last edit was rejected. I think the following might work: "How do I use Raspberry Pi to create a web application for my sensors?"

Comment: And this question does exactly relate to the Pi since the Pi has the most users. Arduino's don't do this kinda stuff. Pi is perfect.

Comment: Joan is more on the ball here by implying this is an opinion oriented question.  Those are more appropriate to a discussion forum.  The issue is there is no objectively correct answer, and it is akin to, e.g., "Which is the best programming language for a web server?" -> That is just a popularity contest (and begs the question *for whom*).  Asking a more specific question, such as "How can I store ______ in an SQL [or OO, etc.] database?" is a bit more objective.

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics *"How do I use Raspberry Pi to create a web application for my sensors?"* -> Please no. That is way too broad (["If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).  If you want to write a blog, write a blog (or tutorial, etc).  Since there are a lot of such things already out there, this should be an easy topic for someone to research using a search engine.  Where we come in is when someone needs an explanation for something they don't understand, or has problem in implementation.

Comment: Hmm. I'm having difficulty thinking of where else in the world Tom and I might have exchanged useful information as we did here thanks to SE. What could Tom have typed? When I researched I got zip. Nothing.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/how-to-handle-open-ended-questions

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: This question is dangerously close to being an opinion question, which is more appropriate for Reddit. But I've tried to cast this answer as a "here's a working example". And you yourself have found another.

Having recently asked myself the same question for the same reason I will share what I know.  I use NodeJs because Javascript is common to front/back end. I use SQLLite because it's free and SQL hasn't changed in decades. You can poke around my repo (https://github.com/oyamist) for ideas. It handles I2C, W1 etc. The downside of using OyaMist is that most hobbyists use Python and products such as HomeAutomation. I wanted something more robust.

Your question is broad, so the answer will be as well:

Web: NodeJS with express.js is great because Javascript can be used as a single language for front/back end. Vue or React are good choices for front-end. I use Vue.

Database: SQL is good for working with time series that sensors collect. I chose SQLLite3. SQL hasn't changed in decades.

SensorSoftware: The choice of Javascript points to rpio although Python libraries are more common.

Comment: I found a very interesting tutorial using express Js, and mongoDB, here's the link : https://webapplog.com/express-js-4-node-js-and-mongodb-rest-api-tutorial/

Comment: OyaMist uses express. MongoDB is a hash database. SQL is qood for time series, which sensors collect. I would consider MongoDB for tracking plants for example, but if you have SQL anyhow, just use that.

Comment: note to moderators: I have tried to eliminate the opinion basis by turning the question into a how question. My example is factual. Others exist as found by the OP. The question actually relates to "how to think about a prolbem" Hopefully i've addressed that.